# What is the purpose of the second parameter of the "queue" method of async?

Tags: node.js, async.js

In the syntax of the `queue` method of `async` there is the second argument , like in this example :

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) 
                    {
                        console.log('hello ' + task.name);
                        callback();
                    }
                   , 2);
```

What does this second argument represent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrency, as taken from the docs "for determining how many worker functions should be run in parallel."  Basically how many functions to run at once

https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue